# Writing data to excel file from C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, excel, office-interop

Building an app that pulls data from SQL Server, creates a new excel file, throws that data in and saves the file to a remote server.

Edit. I have researched and found several ways of doing this and the most pertinent to my particular situation seem to be doing it in the stored proc that is pulling the data, or in the app that fires the SP, either using the excel interop library in C#, or using the ROWSET functions in SQL Server.

I have no preference other than using the latest technology.  As it pertains to ROWSET functions and the Excel Interop library, ss there anything newer, or are these the current tried and true methods.  Know of any good tutorials?

Comment: have you done a constructive and extensive google search.. are you familiar with `SSIS` which was `DTS` back in the day.. there are so many different ways to writing and or saving data to excel there is no 1 right way ..you will need to do a little bit more research on your end.. try `google or YouTube`

Comment: While you are using googling take a look at epplus also.

Comment: I am familiar with SSIS, and I have already counted it out due to other steps I have to do with the data before and after. So from the research I have done, I have determined my best options are either doing it directly from within my app or doing it in the stored procedure I am writing to pull the data.

Comment: I looked at OPENROWSET and I think that based on the examples shown on the `msdn` site.. this could be your best option question is are you familiar with SQL if so .. why not try it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`OPENROWSET`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190312.aspx) is the best if your working with SQL Server, much faster implementation compared to Interop.

[Example implementation](http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=49926) for export\import and creating new Excel file.